# Detecting if a mac is signed into iCloud also getting the username

Tags: cocoa, icloud, detection

There is surely a method of detecting this!

Can anyone shed some light on this please?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to know this? What possible good is the user's iCloud username to you?

Comment: I don't need their username, i need a variable that will display their signed in username...

Comment: The main thing i need is to detect if the user is signed into any iCloud account